# Clean url not working when hyphen in the url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm working on a web application where user can create their profile and see them, so when they create their account I store their username in slug table, eg. if the name is 'Dan Jose' the slug will be stored as Dan-Jose. And when user visits the url eg index.php/Dan-Jose he/she can see the profile. 
But when I put hyphen in it, it redirects to 404. 
And when I change the slug to Dan and type in URL, it shows the right profile.

This is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ index.php?profile=$1 [NC]

# Return 404 if original request is .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]

ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/application/404
```

```
if(isset($_GET['profile'])){
        $profile = $_GET['profile'];
        if($dbqueries->Query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE slug = ?', [$profile])){
            if($dbqueries->rowCount() > 0){
                $row = $dbqueries->fetch();
                $status = $row->status;
                $profileId = $row->id;
                if($status == 1){
                    echo 'Goodd';
                }
                else{
                    header('Location: 404');
                }
            }
            else{
                header('Location: 404');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it because of this? `^([a-z]+)$`?

Comment: How do I fix this, sorry I'm weak in Regex and htaccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)$ index.php?profile=$1 [NC]
```